# Install windows ssh server

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-server-2016, windows-service

I need some help here. I am kind of new to server side stuff. 
I am trying to install SSH on my windows server (Windows Server 2016, 64-bit Operating System). This is the steps i tried:

1.copied this zip file (OpenSSH-Win64.zip) from github "https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases".

2. Extracted this to files to C:\Program Files\Openssh-Win64

3.In Powershell i executed the following commands (in screenshot). I get the message "sshd and ssh-agent services successfully installed". [image]

4. When i go to services (Control Pannel --> Administrative Tools --> Services), i dont find sshd service in there. 
   [image]

Is there something i am missing, How do i start/stop sshd from services.

Thanks,
SP

Comment: https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something i am missing, How do i start/stop sshd from
>   services.

Hi you are looking at the wrong place.. look for Openssh because what you have installed is openssh.

Look for openssh not under letter s referred by "sshd"

[image]

`Service name` and `display name` are two different things.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use PowerShell to start or stop service. Using below commands. (uses service name "sshd" as follows)

Start ssh service

```
 start-Service sshd
```

Stop ssh service

```
Stop-Service sshd
```

To view all services use following

```
 Get-Service
```

**see**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-service?view=powershell-7

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-7

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-7

Comment: Thank you. I am able to find the two services u mentioned.  My bad, i was looking at a link which had mentioned to check sshd... did not realize service name and display names were different... thanks again...

Comment: If this was the answer to your problem, pls consider marking it as the answer. so that someone else like you can easily locate the answer https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

When I want SSH / SSHD on a Windows box, I use Cygwin. https://www.cygwin.com/

I use Cygwin because it has a much better shell experience, and so much more, while also giving you command-line access to manipulate services as Aravinda has shown you in their answer via a windows-interface. You not only get OpenSSH, you get an sshd server, ssh clients, etc, etc.

There's so much more you can do with Cygwin, it's not something I can easily summarize except to say it's like converting your Windows box into a Unix or Linux system, and ALL that means (the list of software packages is amazing). I urge you to check it out.